# MySQL Returned Messages - Success, Failed, what else?

Tags: php, mysql

This may be a really quick answer for some, but I cannot locate the relevant info on MySQL (Maybe my search terms or wording is way off)

Basically, I have a PHP Script that imports content into a MySQL Database with a simple replace statement from `FILE` into table. Now when it fails, we get a nice message back from MySQL (well, an ugly kind of misleading message back).

But what are the messages when it is successful?

Part of my code collects a large qty of TXT files and merges them into a single file, ready to be imported.

Now, I do not want to delete the array of TXT files, until I know whether MySQL returns "Success." If it fails, I want to add another statement to trigger a email.

```
    $conn = new mysqli($databasehost, $databaseusername, $databasepassword,       $databasename);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

So if the `$conn==Success` then go ahead and check if the files exist and delete them.

Can anyone point me to the relevent page or info? What are the returned messages from MySQL so I can start adding some `IF` statements?

Comment: See here : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-errno.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I had what i like to refer to as a complete brain fart: 
I already had the code structured, i just didnt think about it

```
$sqlimport = "
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$File'
REPLACE INTO TABLE `TABEL1`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '$fieldseparator'
" ;

if ($conn->query($sqlimport) === TRUE) {
    echo "<br>Data Imported from " .$File." OK!";
<!--PUT CODE TO DELETE ARRAY FILES -->   

} else {
    echo "<br>Error: " . $sqlimport . "<br>" . $conn->error;
<!-- DID NOT IMPORT, TRIGGER EMAIL-->    

}
```